# Is there any second way to change font size!

Tags: fontsize, times

I am using a specific latex template for my thesis. But I cannot change the font size, that I want to have 14pt. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[MACS,english]{gucthesis}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{2 cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{2 cm}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}   
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
... ... 
\end{document}
```

I know `\documentclass[14pt]{article}` works, and that is the common method for this problem, but as I said I am using very specific templates, it is not working in my case. Is there any other way I can control over the font size.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually `\documentclass[14pt]{article}` does not work.  Only 10pt, 11pt, and 12pt are valid options.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}`

Answer (score 6):

You can use fontsize selectfont :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}

Coucou
\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont
Coucou
\fontsize{28pt}{28pt}\selectfont
Coucou

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If using \fontsize, you probably want the line space to be a little larger than the font: \fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont

Answer (score 3):

As Steven already mentioned in the comments only 10pt, 11pt and 12pt are valid font sizes. If you want to use an even bigger font size you can use the `extsizes` package.

```
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
```